# C# MAUI app - Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f080147 on Android

Tags: android, maui, illegalargumentexception, tabbedpage

I have created a sample C# project to demonstrate what I want to achieve. Here, you can check it: [GiHub sample](https://github.com/Mortens4444/TabbedPageTestApp)

In the example, when I press the button on MainPage, I encounter the following error in Visual Studio Community 2022 (64 bit) - Current Version 17.8.5 on Android Emulator - Pixel 5.

Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException
Message=No view found for id 0x7f080147 (com.companyname.tabbedpagetestapp:id/navigationlayout_toptabs) for fragment ViewFragment{4ddc8ef} (1c250268-2232-41b3-8c18-cb3a65799ebc id=0x7f080147)

On Windows it's a bit buggy, but works (sometimes).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I found a working sample here: https://github.com/dotnet/maui-samples/tree/main/8.0/Navigation/TabbedPage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find this tip in the doc [TabbedPage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/pages/tabbedpage?view=net-maui-8.0):

> **Warning**
>
> **TabbedPage** is incompatible with .NET MAUI Shell apps, and an exception
> will be thrown if you attempt to use **TabbedPage** in a Shell app.

In other words, `TabbedPage` cannot be used together with [`Shell`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfc2j.png). Otherwise it will cause an error.

You can also see the official sample `App.xaml.cs`
file, which looks like this:

```cs
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new AppTabbedPage();
    }
}
```

instead of:

```cs
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new AppShell();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I missed this AppShell thing. It would be great to fix it on AppShell as well, or at least throw a NotSupportedException, to be clear for others like me.